A question about a step in a proof of $\log_{F_{n+1} } F_n < \log_{F_{n+2} }F_{n+1}.$
The question is about this proof.
In the proof of case 1, the last two steps are
$$\implies (\log F_{n} + \log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$$
$$\implies (\log F_{n} + \log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}))^2 = (\log(F_n\cdot (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})))^2 = \log(F_{n+1}^2)^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2} $$
On the left-hand side, why can we change $(\log F_{n} + \log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})^2$ to $(\log F_{n} + \log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}))^2$?
I think it is assuming $\log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}<\log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})$
I verified it for first 100 terms: WolframAlpha
How to prove $\log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}<\log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})$? Thanks.

I too don't understand the reason. Maybe you can ask the person who answered it. I have a rather different proof for a large n using $φ$ but I think you already may know it

Ok, I have worked it out.
$\log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}<\log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})$
is equivalent to
$\log(1-\dfrac{1}{F_nF_{n+2}})>-\dfrac1{F_n}$
Since $F_{n+2}>2F_n$, we only have to prove
$\log(1-\dfrac{1}{2F_n^2})>-\dfrac1{F_n}$
We only have to prove $f(x):=\log(1-\dfrac{1}{2x^2})+\dfrac1{x}$ is positive for $x>2$
$f'(x)=-\dfrac{2 x^2 - 2 x - 1}{x^2 (2 x^2 - 1)}<0$ for $x>2$
So $f$ is decreasing for $x>2$, but since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, we get $f(x)>0$.
